# How do you insert a newline in an RDL Textbox?

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

How do you insert a newline in an RDL-2005 textbox definition ?

Example: how to display FooNewline on a newline inside the textbox:

```
`<Textbox Name=""RdlDescriptorLegendTextbox"">                                
      <Value>Foo FooNewline</Value>
</Textbox>`
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

edit textbox expression 
try some thing like

```
 ="1st line" & vbcrlf & "2nd line"
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. I'm not working on rdl project anymore, hence not able to validate this idea.

Comment: @sthiers the answer was put for the benefit of the masses on the internet. Obviously his answer two years later is not relevant to you... at least I hope you wouldn't be waiting that long! :D

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, however I'm able to do it like so:

```
<Textbox Name="textbox10">
   <Value>Foo
    FoodNewline</Value>
</Textbox>
```